# Create grouped UITableView with sections

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create something that looks like this:
[image]

But the user will be able to add more rows to each section at runtime using a button in the section footer. How can I groups this?

Answer (score 0):

go for given link it will clear your concept about grouped table view it given some great examples  https://github.com/StorminGorman/MultipleTableViewSectionsExample

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve grouped table view with multiple sections using following third party library. I have used following library many times , this library easy to use and also provide easy customization.
https://github.com/LaurentiuUngur/LUExpandableTableView

Comment: But I am not trying to make a expandable and collapsible sections, I am trying to make something like this: https://ibb.co/g6qd2TC